# Conversion of msi to executable with parameters

Tags: windows, windows-installer, exe, executable

The requirement is to convert an msi to a executable file. There are tools available to convert the msi to .exe . But here while executing the msi a lot of parameters passed . This is achieved by writing a batch script and running it from the location of .msi . Now the requirement is to convert the .msi to .exe with parameters passed during conversion.

Is there a way to achieve this using programming/ any tools available? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't "convert" an MSI to an EXE.  You can only encapsulate it inside a self extracting EXE that calls the MSI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use any installer tools like InstallShield, Advanced Installer, etc. which have prerequisites support. Then, you can add the MSI as a prerequisite to an EXE installation package.